# How to remove Assign to Volunteer Project button in Standard Contact List View Page

Tags: contact, list-view, list-button

I logged in to my developer org and upon checking the standard contact list view page, I noticed a button named **Assign to Volunteer Project**. It suddenly appeared among the list of buttons when it is not there before. Also, this is my first time seeing this button. How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is known Summer20 issue, fix is in progress
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001pspcQAA

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this with below steps-

1. Go to the object on which you are seeing this button
2. Find the **Search Layout for Salesforce classic** menu
3. Once you click that menu, Find **List View** menu.
4. You can see all button present there just uncheck particular checkbox and save it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that button isn't listed at all among buttons to check in List View menu. I tried checking profiles but I cannot find any settings related to volunteer.